# syncdb error on django using mysql

Tags: mysql, django, ubuntu, python-2.7

II'm new on django .
I am using ubuntu 13.04

Although i created the databse through phpmyadmin and also entered the credentials in settings.py
but when i typed in the console

> python manage.py syncdb

i got this error

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "manage.py", line 10, in
>
> execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
>
> File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/**init**.py", line 453, in execute_from_command_line

```
utility.execute()
```

> File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/**init**.py", line 392, in execute

```
self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
```

> File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/**init**.py", line 272, in fetch_command

```
klass = load_command_class(app_name, subcommand)
```

> File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/**init**.py", line 77, in load_command_class

```
module = import_module('%s.management.commands.%s' % (app_name, name))
```

> File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/utils/importlib.py", line 35, in import_module

```
__import__(name)
```

> File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/commands/syncdb.py", line 8, in

```
from django.core.management.sql import custom_sql_for_model, emit_post_sync_signal
```

> File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/sql.py", line 9, in

```
from django.db import models
```

> File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/**init**.py", line 40, in

```
backend = load_backend(connection.settings_dict['ENGINE'])
```

> File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/**init**.py", line 34, in **getattr**

```
return getattr(connections[DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS], item)
```

> File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 93, in **getitem**

```
backend = load_backend(db['ENGINE'])
```

> File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 27, in load_backend

```
return import_module('.base', backend_name)
```

> File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/utils/importlib.py", line 35, in import_module

```
__import__(name)
```

> File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 17, in

```
raise ImproperlyConfigured("Error loading MySQLdb module: %s" % e)
```

> django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Error loading MySQLdb module: No module named MySQLdb

i have tried giving extensions to db name in settings.py but it didn't work.
Please suggest what to do.
Thanks !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Or you can do:

```
sudo apt-get install python-mysqldb
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you have mysql installed in you virtual environment

Try

```
pip install MySQL-python
```